# How to Fill-up / rearrange empty space when flex: 0 0 50%; is used in a grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexbox

As I'm no programmer and no clue where to start, I'd like to ask you guys / gals for some input.
In my project I'm using Flexboxgrid to create a semi-flexible portfolio grid. The **before** is the situation as it is right now and I like to achieve the **after** presentation:

[image]

I use Wordpress in combination with WP Pods, so I used a custom field to switch between flex: 0 0 50% and flex: 0 0 100% for each portfolio item, but then my brain freezes.. what to do next?

The **After** situation isn't achievable by pure CSS (flex) I guess, right?
Does anyone knows a solution where **2** 50% height items get combined as a pair? So that there's no unused space. It doesn't matter for me if this would end-up as a horizontal or a vertical combine-method (or maybe random?).

I hope someone could (and would) point me in the right direction :)

This is the base I have:

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.half {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 half">
<img class="box" src="https://www.hielke.net/wp-content/uploads/pastorie-waaxens-logo-bruine-achtergrond-1024x395.jpg">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<img class="box" src="https://www.hielke.net/wp-content/uploads/schotelexpert-featured-1024x1024.jpg">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 half">
<img class="box" src="https://www.hielke.net/wp-content/uploads/emcarcleaning-logo.png">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 half">
<img class="box" src="https://www.hielke.net/wp-content/uploads/pastorie-waaxens-logo-bruine-achtergrond-1024x395.jpg">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<img class="box" src="https://www.hielke.net/wp-content/uploads/reprap3d-featured-1024x1024.jpg">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<img class="box" src="https://www.hielke.net/wp-content/uploads/sceneryworkshop-featured-1024x1024.jpg">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<img class="box" src="https://www.hielke.net/wp-content/uploads/sceneryworkshop-featured-1024x1024.jpg">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<img class="box" src="https://www.hielke.net/wp-content/uploads/sceneryworkshop-featured-1024x1024.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Link to Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hielkio/9L1ousw3/44/